# Should I be concerned about Ubuntu error on my HP WS: "ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND"?

Tags: 22.04, hp, acpi, error-handling, firmware

After recent Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS update, I started getting error message **ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - PV01 (20220331/dspkginit-438)** "
Q1: Should I be concerned about this ERROR?
Q2: Can this error be fixed?

Comment: Try installing or reinstall the `linux-firmware` package.  `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware`

Comment: it did not eliminate the Errors

Comment: If they are only giving you boot errors like that and not all the time while running Ubuntu, there may not be anything you can do about them.  I might be mistaken, but I don't think I did anything special to mine other than changed my `/etc/default/grub` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash"` and they seemed to have disappeared when I did that.

Comment: I get the errors at boot only.

Comment: no luck for me when I tried the change in /etc/default/grub from **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash".

Comment: Did you update grub `sudo update-grub` before you rebooted?

Comment: did you run 'sudo update-grub'?

Comment: I sure did.  I only see those messages if I leave the splash screen on.  Every time you update the `/etc/default/grub` file you're supposed to run `sudo update-grub` for the changes to take effect.  It is easier to edit the `default/grub` file than to manually edit the `/boot/grub.cfg` file that is generated after running `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: the change is not working for my HP WS. This might be a BIOS specific bug that might be addressed by Ubuntu revision or else

Comment: No, but I see a bunch of AE_NOT_FOUND errors when I have my splash screen turned on.  Seeing those errors does not affect my system other than just a nuisance to me at startup.

Answer (score 2):

This is known BIOS level BUG updating the BIOS might help you get rid of it.

You should not be concerned about this error at all.

ACPI entries not conforming to the ACPI specifications is an extremely common problem. Since the problem occurred after an OS upgrade, it would seem that more recent kernels take issue with this particular ACPI error.

Short of performing a BIOS upgrade, assuming one is available for your system, there's nothing much you can do to resolve the issue.

Comment: the HP **BIOS-System Firmware** revision update to the latest version did not help.

Comment: @Dervish007 don't worry about it its all good then